# Bigquery test container is not working for write pending stream

Tags: google-bigquery, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I am trying to test big query batch upload(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-batch-load) using test containers(https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/gcloud/).

But it is not working and getting this error. The tradional way of adding data using insert query is working. But using Data Writer by creating BigQueryWriteClient is not working though BigQueryWriteClient is created successfully

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:112)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:41)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:84)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1127)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:760)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.addListener(ForwardingListenableFuture.java:45)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture.addListener(ApiFutureToListenableFuture.java:49)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1100)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.addCallback(ApiFutures.java:79)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:67)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:87)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:75)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWriteClient.createWriteStream(BigQueryWriteClient.java:257)
```

Comment: Usually we face UNAVAILABLE: io exception when the test container is not properly running, check your container orchestrator like docker.